# Java loading entities partially with JPA 2.1 and hibernate on @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have an entity with a lot of attributes, relationships inside. In a few cases I just need 2 simple attributes, not the rest. I tried using entity graphs, but I always get the complete entries, with all attributs, relationships...

The entity graph in my EECase-entity:

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = EECase.QUERY_ALLCASES, query = "SELECT DISTINCT c FROM EECase c")
})

@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Case.forDropdown", attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode("caseNumber"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("firstNames"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("lastName")
})
```

In my bean I try to get the filtered cases with:

```
public List<EECase> getCasesForDropdown() {
    TypedQuery<EECase> query = getManager().createNamedQuery(EECase.QUERY_ALLCASES, EECase.class);

    EntityGraph<EECase> graph = (EntityGraph<EECase>) getManager().getEntityGraph("Case.forDropdown");
    query.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);

    List<EECase> queryEntity = (List<EECase>) query.getResultList();
    return queryEntity;
}
```

It seems the setHint is getting ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you define a hint, its still an optional thing.

I would suggest a small alternative in the form of a result class in the select being a projection (advised option if you do not plan to update the entity afterwards):

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = EECase.QUERY_ALLCASES
    , query = "SELECT new com.domain.EECase(c.caseNumber, c.firstName, c.lastName) 
               FROM EECase c")
})
```

Keep in mind to place a proper constructor to accept the columns of the projection in a given order.

You can also use a separate POJO to map the results of that query. Not necessarily the entity class itself.

Also keep in mind that you wont be able to select entire dependent entity.. only plain attributes (i assumed that is the case).

Comment: Works fine with a proper constructor, thank you very much.